# Как принять несколько фото?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Хочу принять n-фоток из сообщения и сохранить их под id телеграм юзера. Все гут, но пока работает с 1-й фоткой. Гружу 10-фоток, и оно ассинхронно получает их. Я загрузил 10 фоток - и в методе photo_make_photo_step я вижу только 2штуки, так как другие не успели подгрузиться. Как обойти это? Библиотека `pytelegrambotapi`

```
msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Сделайте фотографии. Как завершите - нажмите Далее⏭️', reply_markup = ok_cancel_menu)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, photo_make_photo_step)

def photo_make_photo_step(message):

    if message.content_type=='photo':
        fileID = message.photo[-1].file_id
        file_info = bot.get_file(fileID)
        downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)

        with open(fileID+".jpg", 'wb') as new_file:
            new_file.write(downloaded_file)
        user.photos.append(fileID+".jpg")
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Добавьте ещё фото или нажмите Далее если закончили выбор')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, photo_bind_photo_step)
        return
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите номер объекта', reply_markup = cancel_menu)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, vvedi_nomer_objecta_step)
```

Comment: Добрый день! Удалось ли вам продвинуться в решении данной проблемы?

Comment: @proritsatel попробуйте через вебхуки юзать

Answer (score 1):

Я частично решил проблему используя декоратор.
Почему я говорю частично - проблема в том, что при отправке скопом например 4 фотографий, загружается только 3. С чем это связано я не знаю.
Надеюсь кому-нибудь поможет.

Это решение сработает только если вы отправляете фото как документ, без сжатия.
Если потеря качества не принципиальна, то можно изменить

```
content_types=['document']
# на
content_types=['photo']
```

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['document'])
def handle_docs_photo(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        file_info = bot.get_file(message.document.file_id)
        downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)

        src = dir + '\\' + message.document.file_name
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, src)
        with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
            new_file.write(downloaded_file)

    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, e)
```

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: Это фактически не является ответом на вопрос. Если у вас есть другие вопросы, вы можете задать их нажав кнопку «[Задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Дополнительно вы можете [добавить вознаграждение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties), чтобы привлечь к вопросу больше внимания, когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет достаточного уровня. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/587563)

Comment: @Jack_oS zя в курсе, что это не является ответом на вопрос. За год тут больше никто и не написал и я решил узнать у пользователя решил ли он проблему. Зачем дублировать вопросы?

Comment: @proritsatel дублировать незачем, вы правы, но можно спросить в коментариях или править вопрос (это актуализирует его) или назначить вознаграждение... в любом случае коммент в ответе - плохая идея, это нарушает правила ресурса

Comment: @Jack_oS на момент ответа у меня не хватало баллов репутиции чтобы прокомментировать решение. А сейчас есть примерное решение, поэтому свой комментарий я изменил на решение.