# Скачивание нескольких фото или файлов pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, email

пишу бота на Python 3 который отправляет фото из телеграмм на e-mail. Подскажите как реализовать скачивание и отправку альбома или несколько фотографий? Скачивается и отправляется только 1 фотография. Спасибо за ответы

```
try:
            file_info = bot.get_file(message.photo[len(message.photo)-1].file_id)
            downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
            filename = message.photo[0].file_id + '.jpg'
            text = MIMEText('Привет')

            attachment = MIMEApplication(downloaded_file)
            attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename = filename)
            msg.attach(attachment)
            
        except TypeError:
            pass

        try:
            file_info = bot.get_file(message.document.file_id)
            downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
            filename = message.document.file_name
            text = MIMEText('Привет')

            attachment = MIMEApplication(downloaded_file)
            attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename = filename)
            msg.attach(attachment)
```

Comment: Архивом попробуйте отправлять

Comment: что бы не городить кучу try except можно проверять content_type у вашего message

Comment: @dIm0n Не получается скачать больше одной фотографии

Comment: @Bonbaron архивом пробовали?

Comment: @dIm0n возможно не правильно задал вопрос, как мне можно получить 2,3 или больше фотографий отправленных боту? Если можно как-то архивом покажите пожалуйста код как это можно сделать?

Comment: @Bonbaron ну вот совсем недавно вопрос же был https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1155112/398802

Comment: @dIm0n тот код который представлен в вопросе скачивает только 1 фотографию, мне бы хотелось чтобы скачивалось несколько фото, при чём столько сколько отправит пользователь. Вопрос не только в отправке, но и в получении фото из телеграмм

Comment: @Bonbaron код в вопросе отправляет 1 файл, почему нельзя поместить нужные вам >1 фотографии в 1 архив и отправить его, а на месте распаковать?

Comment: @dIm0n Одна фотография отправляется и без архива. Вопрос как изменить код чтобы скачивалось несколько фотографий. Например я отправляю 5 фото и чтобы скачалось 5 фото

Comment: @Bonbaron ладно, похоже я вам помочь не могу :)

Comment: @Bonbaron подскажите, удалось ли Вам решить данную проблему?

Comment: @dlm0n с отправкой архивом есть небольшая сложность. Вопрос был именно в том, можно ли отправить с телефона несколько разрозненных файлов. Заниматься архивированием черех телефон немного странно

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как принять несколько фото?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084144/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be)

Answer (score 1):

Я частично решил проблему используя декоратор.
Почему я говорю частично - проблема в том, что при отправке скопом например 4 фотографий, загружается только 3. С чем это связано я не знаю.
Надеюсь кому-нибудь поможет.

Это решение сработает только если вы отправляете фото как документ, без сжатия.
Если потеря качества не принципиальна, то можно изменить

```
content_types=['photo']
```

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['document'])
def handle_docs_photo(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        file_info = bot.get_file(message.document.file_id)
        downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)

        src = dir + '\\' + message.document.file_name
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, src)
        with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
            new_file.write(downloaded_file)

    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, e)
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, к сожалению такой вариант не подходит, т.к. не хочется ограничивать пользователя в количестве фотографий, хотелось бы чтобы любое количество фотографий отправленных боту обрабатывались.